# How can you vote on comments?

Tags: support, comments, voting, privileges, comment-voting

How do you vote on a comment to a question or answer?
I am not seeing any vote button by any comments.

Is it a privilege that you have to earn by having enough reputation? I only have 16 reputation, so, if it is, I don't think I have it.

Comment: From the faq: "You need 15 reputation to upvote comments".

Comment: @ShadowWizard i know, i just found out. a minute ago i had 18 rep an could up vote on comments and now i have 0 and cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need 15 reputation for that. From the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up):

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or *comment* that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

While voting is primarily meant for posts (questions and answers), the privilege also applies to comments.

Comment: Does voting on a comment change reputation like it does one answers and questions?

Comment: No, it doesn't; from the same article: *Upvotes on a comment help ensure the comment remains visible when there are many comments on a post, but do not give the author any reputation.*